# Coldfusion convert List to Json

Tags: json, coldfusion

Stuck with the following problem.

In Coldfusion I have a List:

```
 <cfset myList = "Jack,Mike,Tom,Jude,Dick">
```

I want to convert myList to a Json in precisely this format :

```
[
  {
    "name": [
             "Jack",
             "Mike",
             "Tom",
             "Jude",
             "Dick"
            ]
  }
]
```

I have been trying with making a Structure and Array and then use serializeJSON, but it's not giving the format I need.

Any suggestions how to get the required Json format from the list?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version of CF?

Comment: CF10, I read you comments about the different versions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go,

```
<cfset myList = "Jack,Mike,Tom,Jude,Dick">
<cfset jsonRequired = structNew()>
<cfset jsonRequired.name = listToArray(myList) >
<cfset j = serializeJSON(jsonRequired)>
<cfdump var ="#j#">
```

This will give you required output.

**Edit:** From comments below

```
<cfset myList = "Jack,Mike,Tom,Jude,Dick">
<cfset jsonRequired = [{name = listToArray(myList)}]>
<cfset j = serializeJSON(jsonRequired)>
<cfdump var ="#j#">
```

Comment: Ooh dear, that's a bit old-school, innit? How about just: `jsonRequired = {name=listtoArray(myList)};`. And if it's on CF11 or later,  `jsonRequired = {name=myList.listAtArray()};`. If on CF2016, then using the `toJson()` method is perhaps better than using the `serialzieJson()` function.

Comment: @AdamCameron, Yes, You are always on the point. Old habits die hard, Isn't it? I will try to make use of new methods and coding style.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, this helps a lot! However in your example I'm missing the first '[' and last ']'

I have solved this by doing 
<cfoutput>[#j#]</cfoutput> 

Not really nice, but it does work for me. But would love to know how to do this the correct way.

Comment: @MrSoolmaan, I have updated code to meet your need. Check out edit part. You haven't mentioned ColdFusion version, Please check Adam Cameron's comment for more info.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much. My version is CF10, I will checkout Adam's comments. Thanks again.